# Can't start xdebug

Tags: apache-2.2, php5, zend, xdebug

I managed to install xdebug and enable it through local php.ini files when needed.

It was working just fine for about a month, but today It doesn't.

If I try to start a debug session with Zend Studio IDE, it gets stuck in "57%  launching: waiting for xdebug session"

If I run this command **$ sudo netstat -tunlp | grep 9000** on server console, I get:

> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*             LISTEN    1609/php-fpm.conf)

**phpinfo reports Xdebug v2.1.0**

**local php.ini**

> zend_extension='/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so'
>
> [xdebug]
>
> xdebug.remote_autostart=Off
>
> xdebug.remote_enable=On
>
> xdebug.remote_connect_back = On
>
> xdebug.remote_port=9000
>
> xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
>
> xdebug.profiler_enable = Off
>
> xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = On
>
> xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
>
> xdebug.profiler_output_dir =
>   '/media/data/www/clients/client1/web2/tmp/'
>
> xdebug.remote_log='/media/data/www/clients/client1/web2/log/xdebug_didomenica.log'

Specs

Ubuntu server 12.04, upgraded today

PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4

Xdebug v2.1.0

Any help is really appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just forget it.
With this config options it works! (just changed port to `9001`)

```
zend_extension='/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so'

[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_connect_back = On
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_handler='dbgp'
xdebug.remote_log='/media/data/www/clients/client1/web2/log/xdebuga.log'
xdebug.profiler_enable=Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=Off
xdebug.profiler_output_name=cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir='/media/data/www/clients/client1/web2/tmp/'
```

For some reason, I had to erase my ZendStudio "workspaces" folder, and import all my projects again, and of course, changed por of debugger in `windows->preferences->php->debug->configure`.